# solr search query apply condition in both field (exist OR does not exist)

Tags: solr, lucene, solrj

I have data with different dynamic field. i want to apply the condition in exists field record and i need not exists field records also. My Solr version 6.1.0

```
{"employeeid" : "220",  "displayname_s": "abu", "attr_36977": 55 },
{"employeeid" : "910",  "displayname_s": "test","attr_36400": 565 },
{"employeeid" : "210", "displayname_s": "sam"},
{"employeeid" : "64", "displayname_s": "wel", "attr_36977": 152},
```

i write a query like this

> `(-attrl_36977:[* TO *] OR attrl_36977:[0 TO 100])`

but this query not workout.

the idle result is first three records(***220,910,210***). how to solve the requirement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be explicit about what you're subtracting the first part of your OR statement from:

```
(*:* -attrl_36977:[* TO *]) OR attrl_36977:[0 TO 100]
```

.. will give you any documents that doesn't have a value in `attrl_36977` or a value between 0 and 100 inclusive.

Comment: I spent like 4-5 hrs writing the same logic as @RSK and was scratching my head why am I not getting the data that doesn't have the field. Finally, after this answer, I figured out I had to put ```*:*``` before -. Thanks, man. ie. ```(end_date:[* TO  target] OR (*:* -end_date[* TO *]) ```

Comment: @RaviSigdel It helps to think about it as "- subtracts - but what does it subtract from?". Lucene (and Solr) operates on sets, so when you want to remove something from a set, you'll have to have something to remove it from - `*:*` represents "all the documents in the index". Regular pure negative queries are specially parsed to start with the set that represents all documents, but when you add boolean operators that is no longer the case for each term.

Comment: For me, `*:*` changed the results when using an edismax query. It was removing records I expected in the results. I'm not actually sure why. The solution for me was to use the parens, but not the `*;*` part, so e.g. I'd do `((-attrl_36977:[* TO *]) OR attrl_36977:[0 TO 100])`